# Solving a couple of PDEs (NDSolve :There are fewer dependent variables, {b[t,y]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.)

Tags: differential-equations

I'm new to mathematica. I'm trying to solve a couple of PDEs. My code is here.

```
pde=NDSolve[
{D[H[y],{y,2}]+(D[H[y],y])^2-D[H[y],y]*D[b[t,y],y]/b[t,y]-(b[t,y])^2==0,
7*(D[H[y],y]/b[t,y])^2+Exp[6*H[y]*t]*(5*D[H[y],t]*D[b[t,y],t]/b[t,y]+D[b[t,y],{t,2}]/b[t,y])==0},
b,{t,0,10},{y,0,10}]
```

When I try to solve it, mathmatica says "NDSolve :There are fewer dependent variables, {b[t,y]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined." although there is no initial condition(result is same even if I add initial condition. I tried H[t,y] instead of H[y] also). there is only two equations. what's wrong with my code?

p.s. initial condition is here: H[0]=H'[0]=H''[0]=1, b[0,y]=b[t,0]=b[10,y]=b[t,10]=1.

Comment: What is the original equation(s) ? What are the independent and dependent variables ? Without knowing these we cannot start solving it.